# Pass HttpClient uri to Blazor WASM using nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to pass settings from the nginx host in a docker container to a standalone blazor webassembly (wasm) application?

In my case I want to pass the HttpClient url to the wasm application, so that the requests were send to the correct http-endpoint (api).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That is an excellent question. We had the same because we want to have a generic image everyone can use and came up with this solution for now.

We are using an additional script as startup for the container. This script is using `jq` to change the `appsettings.json` at startup. It is only doing it on the first start, that means if you stop the container and start it again, it should directly start `nginx`.

Most important files:

- `build/frontend.Dockerfile`
- `build/Frontend/docker-entrypoint-tm.sh`

This is our project [Tournament Manager](https://gitlab.com/clanwars/tournament-manager) have a look there.

Comment: I just thought a littlebit more about the problem. If you deploy your application with kubernetes you could simply use a `ConfigMap` to create your `appsettings.json`.